# Elm - onBlur from dynamically created input

Tags: events, elm

The onBlur event in Html.Events does not allow for any values to be passed with it, as far as I understand. There is a way to make it include the value of the input (see this question for example: [Elm Html.Events - Pass input value to onBlur message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893783/elm-html-events-pass-input-value-to-onblur-message)), but how can I also make it include another value?

My use case is that I generate a list (ul) from a list I have in my model, and this list can be any size, so I can not have a specific message for each input. Instead I would like something like this for each item:

```
            input
                [ value someValue
                , onBlur UpdateItem uniqueId
                ]
                []
```

That way I could update the specific item in my model based on the id I got from the onBlur message.

How can I do this?

Update:
To clarify my question: I also need the value from the input, so I need to both pass my id *and* get the targetValue (as in the question I linked above).

(For future visitors: I use **Elm 0.18**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use onChange, which you need to define yourself, and is triggered at the same time as the blur event.

```
onChange : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onChange msgCreator =
    Html.Events.on "change" (Json.map msgCreator Html.Events.targetValue)
```

then define a message to carry the new value and its id

```
type Msg 
   = UpdateItem Id String
```

and then make sure to use the `defaultValue` attribute (rather than `value`)

```
 input 
     [ defaultValue someValue
     , onChange (UpdateItem uniqueId) ]
     []
```